# How to transform flat data structure into a hierarchical tree structure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a flat data structure that I'm trying to transform into a hierarchical tree structure. The data is an array of objects, where each object has an `id`, `name`, and optionally a `parent` property that refers to the `id` of another object in the array.

Here's an example of my input data:

```js
const inputData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Fruit",
  },
  // ... more data
];
```

I want to transform this data into a tree structure where each object has a `children` array that contains its child objects. The `children` array should be empty if the object has no children.

Here's an example of the desired output:

```js
const outputData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Fruit",
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Apple",
        parent: 1,
      },
      // ... more data
    ],
  },
  // ... more data
];
```

I've tried a few different approaches, but I'm having trouble dealing with the parent-child relationships. Can anyone suggest a good way to transform this data?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filter and map

```js
const inputData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Fruit",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Apple",
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Orange",
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Banana",
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Berry",
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Drink",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Water",
    parent: 6,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Lemonade",
    parent: 6,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "Tea",
    parent: 6,
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Soup",
  },
];

var newData=inputData.filter(i=> !i.parent).map(i=>{
let children=inputData.filter(c=> c.parent == i.id);
return {...i,children}
});

console.log(newData)
```